# java.OutOfMemoryException when using continuous query in Ignite

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I'm using Ignite.NET 2.8.0.20190421 and got OutOfMemoryException when I'm attaching continuous query using ICache.QueryContinuous and listening for an object's changes for a long time.

For example: on the server's side I create the single object in the cache.
Then I start the client and start listening for this object's changes using QueryContinuous. And after I start changing the object on the server's side very often and look for its JVM memory consumption in Java VisualVM - it growths constantly until OutOfMemoryException.

It looks like the server holds all the versions of the changing objects in its memory, although they are useless.

Example:

```
// Our object to store, make it big to easily reproduce the problem
public sealed class DataItem
{
  public int[] Data { get; private set; } = new int[1000000];
}

// Do on the server's side:
// Start Ignite and create cache
while(true)
{
  DataItem item = new DataItem();
  cache.Put(0, item);
  Thread.Sleep(300);
}

// Do on the client's side:
// Start Ignite in client's mode, request cache and start listening
cache.QueryContinuous(query);
```

Full Visual Studio project, that reproduces the problem:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aiu3pq0bidkbbif/IgniteListeners.rar?dl=0

Steps:

1. Start IgniteListeners.exe with any argument to start the server's side, for example, "IgniteListeners.exe s"
2. Start IgniteListeners.exe with no arguments to start the client
3. The server will crash within a minute, you can see in Java VisualVM its JVM memory is constantly growing.

Comment: Does this happen with Ignite 2.7.5? It doesn't sound right, but you are running a development version.

Comment: @StephenDarlington The same situation is with 2.7.5 and below. The first reason to test development build is to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue. It's related to excessive use of memory in continuous queries, `Ignite` node needs to store up to 1000 updates in the buffer. It could lead to OOM if entries are heavy. Here you can track progress https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-11970.